# inverted nested overlines

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Here's a funny one.  The `\overline` command works pretty well when nested.   For example, `\overline{A\overline B}` produces a bar of AB over a bar of B.  Is there some way to reverse or more generally control the order of the stack of bars? For example, how about to produce a bar of B over a bar of AB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example solves the reversed bars with `\phantom` and `\rlap`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \overline{A\overline{B}}
  \mbox{ vs.\@ }
  \rlap{$\phantom{A}\overline{\phantom{\overline{B}}}$}
  \overline{AB}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Woahhh... That is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Since `\overline` spans the full character width already, one can treat the `A` and `B` seperately, in terms of their overlines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\overline{A}\overline{\overline{B}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This idea also worked in the situations I'd had in mind.  It looks like the height of the overline varies with the height of the character.  But I got them to line up as desired by inserting vphantoms.  e.g. 
$$(\overline{A(}\overline{\overline{B\vphantom{(A)}}}\overline{)})
$$

Comment: @mmw It is true that if the constituents are of different heights, a `\vphantom` would be needed.